# Can I view an available message that isn't receivable in a Fifo queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS FIFO queue that uses thousands of message group ids for ordering and exactly-once processing.

Most messages are processed quickly by the consumer, and deleted from the queue.

However since some messages can take a while to process, the `VisibilityTimeout` on the queue is 2 hours.

Occasionally I'll end up with one or two messages showing as *available* in my queue, but they're not *receivable* because a message with the same message group id is in-flight.

I know I can't *receive* these messages, but is there any way to *view* the messages to know which message group id is causing issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **can't view in-flight messages** as they are simply not visible to other consumers.

However, if you have some messages that cause issues, e.g., they are non-receivable, you may consider setting up [dead letter queue (DLQ)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html):

> Dead-letter queues are useful for debugging your application or messaging system because they let you isolate **problematic messages to determine why their processing doesn't succeed**.

This way these "bad" messages will end up in a DLQ, which will allow you to inspect them, be automatically notified about their presence or process them in a different way.